# Four sequences made in a specific way

Tags: number-sequence

```
                                       ?

                                      233

                                       55

                                       13

                                        3

                     ?, 377, 89, 21, 5, 1  4, 25, 145, 850, ?

                                        7

                                        40

                                       235

                                       1375

                                        ?
```

What comes next (where the question marks are)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Very Tricky!

Here are the most obvious patterns that come to mind:

Left branch:

> Pattern: $ x_n = 4 x_{n-1} + x_{n-2} $

Top branch:

> Pattern: $ x_n = 4 x_{n-1} + x_{n-2} $

Right branch:

> Pattern: $ x_n = 5 (x_{n-1} + x_{n-2}) $

Bottom branch:

> Pattern: $ x_n = 6 x_{n-1} - 5 x_{n-3} $

But then there's the *metapattern*, that is, the pattern of patterns, that doesn't look quite right:

> The top pattern is the same as the one to the left, but the bottom and the right look different.

That doesn't fit the puzzle's aesthetics at all, but what can we do?

> As long as we ignore the "obvious pattern" for the right branch, we can also get the exact same values by using the "less obvious" pattern from the bottom branch!

So the initial values in the right branch were deliberately chosen to mislead, and the pattern in there is **secretly**

> the same as the one in the bottom branch!

And **then** I woke up and took my hand out of the chamber pot:

> The patterns **are** the same. The bottom branch pattern **is** also $$ x_n = 5 (x_{n-1} + x_{n-2}) $$ and any sequence generated by that pattern automatically will also have the $$ x_n = 6 x_{n-1} - 5 x_{n-3} $$ pattern: we get from the former to the latter by adding an $x_{n-1}$ and subtracting $5(x_{n-2} + x_{n-3})$, which clearly are the same number according to the former equation. So the "obvious" pattern we got for the bottom branch earlier clearly **wasn't the obvious one**, since the one for the right branch takes only two numbers to initialise. Ouch!

So then let's just fill in the question marks in, while I bow my head in shame:

> ```
>                                       987
>
>                                       233
>
>                                        55
>
>                                        13
>
>                                         3
>
> >                 1597, 377, 89, 21, 5, 1  4, 25, 145, 850, 4975
>
>                                         7
>
>                                        40
>
>                                       235
>
>                                      1375
>
>                                      8050
> ```

I'm leaving the story as it is, since it depicts my thought process, which might bring some entertainment (or at least schadenfreude) to some of you. I'm only hoping there isn't some other even more obvious patter I'm also missing here :-)

Comment: @Βass You are very close to the correct answers but not quite right.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis I don't see how that would work: either my numbers are correct, or they are utter garbage; there's no in-between really. The first case occurs if each branch is an independently solvable, iterative sequence, as I've assumed with reasonably strong evidence (there are three matching steps in every sequence, so there are 12 data points in support of this theory). The other case occurs if the sequences are something else: any semblance between my answers and the correct ones must then surely be completely coincidental.

Comment: The sequences work like this: L+Q ,   2L+Q   From the first relation we obtain the sequence 1,2,5,13,34...…..   From the second relation we obtain the sequence 1,3,8,21,55..... Fibonacci did not invent these sequences, he found them. The above sequences have different coefficients.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis Your comment contains many sentences that make sense on their own. However, putting them together, I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to say. (That's mostly because I'm assuming you are **not** trying to say that my answer is exactly correct, apart from not correctly guessing which of the many interchangeable methods of generating the sequences was used.)

Comment: My sequences are correct as you can see in my comment.  if I reveal the coefficients of the formulas all the sequences would make perfect sense to you. I am sad I get punished because you cannot answer the question. If you want me to reveal the formulas please ask for that.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis You are not being punished for that. That was just me reversing my upvote because you seem to be saying that finding the correct numbers isn't enough, I also have to guess which one of the infinitely many possible methods you used to get those numbers. For example, I'm pretty sure you got the top branch by choosing every third Fibonacci number. That's one method of arriving at 987 for the next number. Calculating $4\times233 + 55$, as I did, is another way. The methods are exactly equivalent. You used the exact same method for the left branch, and got 1597, just like I did.

Comment: The numbers  987 and1597 are corect

Comment: @VassilisParassidis If you have some other results for the other two numbers, please double check your math to ensure we are not quibbling about a silly typo somewhere. I've just checked my math for the fifth time, so I'm pretty confident about the results, in particular because the other two results were confirmed correct, and these two use a very similar pattern.